# Why am I receiving an Illegal Instruction 4 when using Pathlib in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib, python-watchdog

I'm working on a project that watches my desktop using Watchdog, and sends a specified filetype to an external API that does some jiggery-pokery, then returns it to my desktop within a created folder.

I'm using Python 3.8, and Pathlib's `expanduser` rather than the old `os.path.expanduser` method, because I want to make this platform-agnostic rather than macOS only in a nicer way. Here's the class I'm focusing on:

```
class ObserverLoop:
    def __init__(self):
        self.folder = Path("~/Desktop")
        # self.working_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser("~/" + "/Desktop/"))
        self.working_path = self.folder.expanduser()
        self.event_handler = MonitorFolderChanges(self.working_path)

    def start_loop(self):
        tf.key = secrets.api_key
        observer = Observer()

        observer.schedule(self.event_handler, self.working_path, recursive=False)
        observer.start()

        try:
            while observer.is_alive():
                observer.join(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            observer.stop()

        observer.join()
```

For reference, here's part of the `MonitorFolderChanges` class used here:

```
class MonitorFolderChanges(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, working_path):
        self.path = working_path

    def on_modified(self, event):
        file_exts = [".jpg", ".jpeg" ".png", ".svg", ".gif"]
        images = []

        for file in Path(self.path).glob("**/*"):
            # for file in os.listdir(self.path):
            full_path = PurePath(f"{self.path}/{file}")

            if full_path.suffix.lower() in file_exts: <snip>
```

However, while I can get this to work using `os.path`, I get an illegal instruction 4 when using `Pathlib`.

I've narrowed this down – I think – to where the `observer` instance is created. My Python skills are not expert, but I don't believe I've got anything wrong here. Is this a conflict with Watchdog that I can fix, or is there another answer I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to upgrade Watchdog to 0.10.3, as this fixes the issues with Pathlib.